# JAX RS Jersey Rest Webservice posting a array generated by input from user

Tags: rest, post, jersey, jax-rs

I am making a smart app, which registers energy expenditure of appliances in the home of the user. It can also shut down appliances if they are on outside a certain time interval, for example the the user wants his computer to be off at night.

I have the following problem, the user has to enter the number of appliances he wants to register, then there will be generated that number of textfields, so he can enter the time intervals of these appliances. I have saved this input already in an array, using some javascript, but how can I send this over with a post request? I thought I had to use the @FormParam, just as with posting a username and a password, but this doesn't seem to work for me. This is what the applianceInfo.html looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>

<form action="/Smart_Webapp/rest/hello/applianceInfo"
    method="POST" oninput="array.value=getArray(numberOfAppliances.value)">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="numberOfAppliances" id="numberOfAppliances" />
        <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Create" onclick="createTextFields(numberOfAppliances.value);" />
        <input type="button" name="saveButton" id="saveButton" value="Save" onclick="getArray(numberOfAppliances.value);" />
        <div id="textFields"></div>
        <output name="array" for="numberOfAppliances"></output>
    </p>    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <p id="array"></p>
</form>

<script>
function createTextFields(nums){
    var input = "";
    for(i=0;i<nums;i++){
        input += "<input type='text' id='name" + i + "'" + "  + '  /> "
            +"<input type='text' id='start" + i + "'" + "  + '  /> "
            +"<input type='text' id='end" + i + "'" + "  + '  /> <br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("textFields").innerHTML = input;
}

function getArray(nums) {
    var array = [];
    for(i=0;i<nums;i++) {
        array[i] = []
        array[i].push(document.getElementById("name" + i).value);
        array[i].push(document.getElementById("start" + i).value);  
        array[i].push(document.getElementById("end" + i).value);
    }
document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = array.toString();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The following function will be called on the server side:

```
  @Path("/applianceInfo")
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  public void applianceInfo(@FormParam("array") String array, @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException { 
      System.out.println(array);
  }
```

What I want is the array to be received there, but when printing it, it just prints 'null'. However when I try the same thing with for example numberOfAppliances, it receives it nicely and prints it out just fine. First I thought it was because maybe after the submit button is pressed the array will be created. So it would post the empty array variable and then generate the array. So I made a extra save button to check this, but this didn't fix my problem.

So my question is how can I send this array with the input of the appliances filled in by the user over to the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<output>` doesn't get sent in the form submission. You should instead add `name` attributes to all your `<input>` elements you dynamically create.

```
 input += "<input name='array' type='text' id='name" + i + "'" + "  + '  /> "
       + "<input name='array' type='text' id='start" + i + "'" + "  + '  /> "
       + "<input name='array' type='text' id='end" + i + "'" + "  + '  /> <br/>";
```

Then you can do this in your resource method.

```
@Path("/applianceInfo")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response applianceInfo(@FormParam("array") List<String> array)
```

Remember the `name` attribute value of the `<input>` element, that will be the key for the for parameter. So the request body will look like

```
array=hello&array=world&array=blah
```

That's why we use a `List` here, because there are multiple parameters with the key `array`.

If you want to group each row together, maybe consider a different format like JSON, to send the data.